# "fuzzy key matching" for a data.table merge

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to match workers from year to year using name strings and a measure of experience. Experience can only increase by at most one from year to year, so I'd like to use this to help matching when other metrics fail.

For example:

```
dt1<-data.table(name=c("jane doe","jane doe",
                       "john doe","jane smith"),
                exp=c(0.,5,1,2),id=1:4,key="name")
dt2<-data.table(name=c("jane doe","jane doe",
                       "john doe","jane smith"),
                exp=c(0,30,1.5,2),key="name")
```

I want to match the first "jane doe" in `dt1` to the first "jane doe" in `dt2`. The latter "jane doe"s don't match, because they're clearly different people (based on vastly different experience levels).

I'd also like to add some flags to know I matched these people in this way later on down the line. Here's my first pass:

```
dt2[dt1,`:=`(id=ifelse(exp<=i.exp+1,i.id,NA),
             flag=ifelse(exp<=i.exp+1,i.id,NA))]
```

But this is not working--here's what that gives me:

```
> dt2
         name  exp id flag
1:   jane doe  0.0  2    2
2:   jane doe 30.0 NA   NA
3: jane smith  2.0  4    4
4:   john doe  1.5  3    3
```

It seems properly to have missed  matching the latter "jane doe", but appears to have matched the first "jane doe" to the wrong prior "jane doe". I'm not quite sure why this is; anyway, it seems preferable to have a way to incorporate the matching on `exp` *before* instead of after joining--this would also clean up the `ifelse` mess in defining the new variables. Any suggestions?

---

For clarity, here's the desired output:

```
> dt2
         name  exp id flag
1:   jane doe  1.0  1    1
2:   jane doe 30.0 NA   NA
3: jane smith  2.0  4    1
4:   john doe  1.5  3    1
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to match both by `name` *and* by `exp`? in other words,  all the "jane doe"s in `df1` are different people?

Comment: Anyway, I'm not entirely sure, but maybe you are looking for `setkey(dt1, name, exp) ; setkey(dt2, name, exp) ; dt2[dt1, id := i.id, roll = -1L]`?

Comment: Perfect! Never quite understood what `roll` does--finally found an example. So `roll=-2L` would match anyone with `exp` at most 2 less; `roll=1L` would match anyone with `exp` at most 1 _more_, and so on.  `roll=+Inf` for any `exp` greater, `roll=-Inf` for any `exp` less. What about matching _within_ 1? `roll=c(-1L,1L)` didn't work, and `nearest` doesn't necessarily work.

Comment: For intervals, you may want to look at `foverlaps`.. But there are some FRs on `roll`..

Comment: FRs? Future Revisions?

Comment: Feature request on GitHub... Arun is the maintainer of the `data.table` package.

Comment: `foverlaps` is a good tool to know, thanks. If someone wants to write up this comment section, I can close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case the join isn't really "fuzzy". All you trying to do is to join by `name` by `exp` while allowing one 1 year distance per match. This is good use for a *rolling join* with a `-1L` specification.

First we will correctly key the data sets

```
setkey(dt1, name, exp) 
setkey(dt2, name, exp)
```

Then, we will perform the rolling join while passing `-1L` as its value

```
dt2[dt1, `:=`(id = i.id, flag = 1L), roll = -1L]
df2
#          name  exp id flag
# 1:   jane doe  0.0  1    1
# 2:   jane doe 30.0 NA   NA
# 3: jane smith  2.0  4    1
# 4:   john doe  1.5  3    1
```

---

In future, if you''ll need to conduct an interval join such as `c(1L, -1L)` you can take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3001626+foverlaps) for some examples of the `foverlaps` function.